# В чем преимущество контейнеров PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlayout

Зачем нужны вообще контейнеры?

Про то, что они автоматически растягивают виджеты я уже понял, но есть ли другие полезные свойства контейнеров?

Comment: Что вы вкладываете в понятие контейнеры? Судя по вопросу вы из не используете или используете? Покажите минимально-воспроизводимый приме, которого будет можно вам продемонстрировать.

Comment: Я их использую только в том случае, если создаю виджет в отдельном классе. Затем виджет добавляю в контейнер, а контейнер уже на окно. Я говорю конкретно о QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout и QFormLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Система компоновки *Qt* предоставляет простой и мощный способ автоматической
организации дочерних виджетов внутри виджета, чтобы гарантировать,
что они эффективно используют доступное пространство.

Qt включает набор классов управления компоновкой,
которые используются для описания компоновки виджетов в пользовательском интерфейсе
приложения.
Эти layouts автоматически позиционируют и изменяют размер виджетов,
когда объем доступного для них места изменяется, гарантируя,
что они единообразно расположены и пользовательский интерфейс в целом
остается пригодным для использования.

Все подклассы QWidget могут использовать менеджеры компоновки для управления своими
дочерними элементами. Функция QWidget::setLayout() применяет layout к виджету.
Когда layout установлен для виджета таким образом, он берет на себя следующие задачи:

- Позиционирование дочерних виджетов
- Разумные размеры по умолчанию для окон
- Разумные минимальные размеры окон
- Обработка изменения размера
- Автоматические обновления при изменении содержимого:

  - Размер шрифта, текст или другое содержимое дочерних виджетов
  - Скрытие или отображение дочернего виджета
  - Удаление дочерних виджетов

...

**P.S.** Без менеджеров компоновки, хорошего приложения не получится.

Answer (score 2):

Контейнеры — это классы общего назначения, которые хранят в себе значения заданного типа. Есть 2 типа контейнеров:

Последовательные — элементы хранятся друг за другом (последовательно). Примерами последовательных контейнеров являются QList, QVector, QLinkedList.

Ассоциативные — элементы хранятся в виде пары ключ-значение. Примерами ассоциативных контейнеров являются QMap и QHash.

**Я сумел ответить на Ваш вопрос? :)**

Comment: Я до этого момента знал только о существовании QVBoxLayout,  QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout и QFormLayout. Это ведь тоже контейнеры?

Comment: Да, конечно! Рад, что Вы улучшили свои знания!

Comment: Да я кроме их названий толком ничего и не знал))

Comment: Но грамотнее их использовать или можно без контейнеров обойтись?

Comment: Если окно Вашего приложения можно растянуть, то лучше использовать контейнеры. Если же Вы указали, что окно растягивать нельзя, то смысла в контейнерах нет.

Comment: Дак ведь растяжение можно реализовать и без контейнеров

Comment: Тогда пока что отложу их изучение)

Comment: Можно. Лучше делать так, как Вам удобнее :)